# get the url scheme of an app

Tags: android, url-scheme

How could i get the `URL Scheme` of an app so that i can open that app inside my app.I have searched and what i get is below:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GALLERY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="cedemo" android:host="com.cedemo.scan" />

        </intent-filter>
```

could anybody help me regarding this @Thanks

Comment: Hey did u get the answer for ur question ???

Answer (score -2):

Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html